# JavaScript new Date() problems

Tags: javascript

Reading a previous question about the `Date` object in JavaScript I pointed out on my notebook the following problem:

```
var date1 = new Date('2015','02','31');
```

The command: `alert(date1.getDay());` runs correctly!

What happens on my computer with IE and Chrome?
If I debug I see:

> `__proto__` Invalid Date

Why? I also write the command as:

```
var date1 = new Date(2015, 2, 10);
```

But the problem continues to be there.

Many thanks for the help

Comment: If you see an `Invalid Date` error, you're probably not passing in those values, as they should work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This is not a bug and is entirely expected.

In JavaScript, inheritance is based on objects.

For some reason - the engine designers thought it would be a great idea that the prototypical date - the one every single date object inherits from would be the invalid date. It's the same as `Date.prototype`. ([Read about it here](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.1))

All JavaScript objects have (In ES6, also non normative) a `__proto__` method that represents what object they inherit from.

What the developer tools is telling you is that your date object inherits from the prototypical date - which is an invalid date. Your date object is just fine.